# fread. Не понятная ошибка при чтении. Поток создается а чтение не происходит

Tags: linux, c, io

Вопрос к знатокам С. Имеется следующий код:

```
  FILE *in_out = NULL;
  FILE *out = NULL;
  axis_t tmp_buf_now;  //struct
  memset(&tmp_buf_now, 0, sizeof(axis_t));
  const char *now = "now_data";  //file 1
  const char *previous = "previous_data";  //file 2

  in_out = fopen(now, "rb+");  //open binary file. Read and write mode
  if (!in_out) {
    if (errno == ENOENT) {  //No such file or directory
      in_out = fopen(now, "wb+");  //Create new file. Read and write mode
      if (!in_out) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  }

  if (!fread(&tmp_buf_now, sizeof(axis_t), 1, in_out)) { //exception - error2
    int en = errno;
    printf("errno %i\n", en);
    if (en != EAGAIN) {
      perror("fread");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  printf("old data\n x:%f, y:%f, z:%f\n", tmp_buf_now.x, tmp_buf_now.y,
         tmp_buf_now.z);
```

errno 2
fread: No such file or directory

Что не так с кодом?
PS: Пишу бинарные данные. ОС - linux. gcc -std=c99.

Answer (score 3):

Очевидно, что в вопросе рассматривается случай, когда файла еще нет и первый вызов `in_out = fopen(now, "rb+");` возвращает `NULL`. *При этом переменная `errno`, естественно, принимает значение `ENOENT`*.

Второй вызов `fopen()` успешно создает файл (пустой).

Поскольку успешные вызовы не меняют значения `errno`, то оно остается тем же самым и после вызова `fread()`, который возвращает 0 (файл же пуст), что в данном случае соответствует `EOF`.

Т.о. вы просто неверно интерпретируете ситуацию и выводите сообщение о не существующей ошибке.

Обратите внимание, что в [man 3 fread](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) написано:

> fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and
>   callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.

---

Возможно следующая модификация кода прояснит ситуацию

```
...
  int old = 1;
  in_out = fopen(now, "rb+");  //open binary file. Read and write mode
  if (!in_out) {
    if (errno == ENOENT) {  //No such file or directory
      in_out = fopen(now, "wb+");  //Create new file. Read and write mode
      if (!in_out) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      } else { 
        tmp_buf_now = (axis_t){1, 2, 3};
        fwrite(&tmp_buf_now, sizeof(axis_t), 1, in_out);
        old = 0; // write initial data to file
      }
    }
  }

  rewind(in_out); 
  errno = 0;
  if (!fread(&tmp_buf_now, sizeof(axis_t), 1, in_out)) { 
    int en = errno;
    printf("errno %i\n", en);
    if (feof(in_out))
      exit((puts("fread -- empty file"), EXIT_SUCCESS));
    else if (ferror(in_out))
      exit((perror("fread"), EXIT_FAILURE));
    else
      exit((perror("fread ???"), EXIT_FAILURE));
  }

  printf("%s data\n x:%f, y:%f, z:%f\n",
     old ? "old" : "new", tmp_buf_now.x, tmp_buf_now.y, tmp_buf_now.z);
```

Обратите внимание на вызов [`rewind()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) перед `fread()`.

В данной ситуации, когда мы сами создаем файл и пишем в него данные, позиция чтения-записи после `fwrite()` будет в конце файла и наш `fread()` вернет 0 так же, как и в случае пустого файла. Поэтому вызываем `rewind()` для позиционирования в начало файла (понятно, что в случае открытия существующего файла этот `rewind()` ни на что не влияет) перед чтением.

Поэкспериментируйте с запуском в случаях как с пустым файлом, так и с его отсутствием.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я правильно понял, что в данном случае не верно интерпретировал ошибку у fread?

Comment: У fread нет никакой ошибки (если не считать логики алгоритма), просто в файле нет данных. Сейчас напишу **update**  ответа.

Comment: Спасибо Вам больше. После , примерно подобной модификации, мой код заработал. Я сделал проверку на feof() и ferror(). Сделал обнуление erron. Все заработало, но так как у меня было усечение файла и небыло обновления позиционирования то образовывалась "дыра" и чтение выдавало нули. После позиционирования запись пошла с начала файла и все пошло как надо.

Comment: @БогданЛещенко,  отлично, рад, что в чем-то помог.

Answer (score -2):

Потому, что по каким-то неясным причинам вы используете fread + errno. Проблема в 1 букве.